# surfire plugin maven : env variable for specific tests

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am facing an issue with Maven and the Surefire plugin.

I have two tests: `testDatePos.java` and `testDateNeg.java` and for each test an environment variable must be set. It is the same environment variable (`DATE_SHIFT`) but not the same value (`-1 and 1`).

Is it possible to configure the section surefire-plugin in the `pom.xml` of maven to have those tests running?

Here is my pom.xml that exclude the `testDatePos.java` to have the `mvn test` running OK (I know this is NOT a solution):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/testDatePos.java</exclude>
      <!-- this test needs the env variable DATE_SHIFT=1 but 
      the test testDateNeg.java needs it at -1 -->
    </excludes>
    <environmentVariables>
      <DATE_SHIFT>-1</DATE_SHIFT>
    </environmentVariables>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the unit tests, cause it sounds weird having an environment variable set to run a unit tests. And from that point this is not really a unit test cause it's depending from the environment.

Comment: hello khmarbaise, in fact this is the class that i am testing that needs the env var. This is a manager for a logical date/time. And i test it with a positive and negative shit.

Comment: Is it the tests that need the environment variable or is it the code under test?

Comment: It's the code under that needs the environment variable, but `testDateNeg.java` (resp. `testDatePos.java`) must be run with `DATE_SHIFT=-1` (resp. `DATE_SHIFT=1`). With eclipse i was doing it with the menu `run configurations > environment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by specifying two different executions of surefire in your pom, and forking each execution.

However, this means that these tests will only work when you're running them from maven, or at least you have to change the configuration everywhere you run them from. So, for the tests which require a environment variable, I would add this to the @Before/@After (or @BeforeClass/@AfterClass) of those specific tests.

```
@Before public void before() {
  System.setProperty("DATE_SHIFT", "-1");
}
```

This way, you don't need to execute the tests in maven for them to work. You'll probably want to store the original value of DATE_SHIFT and restore it at the end of the test.